# Set CSS Class using an Observable

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

Please take a look at [this Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gzGgcCsV431dKj58DD7x?p=preview).

```
    this.obsCount = Observable
      .interval(1000);
```

Do you know how to set the class based on the obsCount Observable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to work in the plunkr you provided ;-) So what is the question?

Comment: it uses the `this.count` variable. I would like to use `this.obsCount` to have a more _cleaner and reactive_ code :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use the async pipe for this to work. The async pipe allows component templates the ability to update with emitted observable events:

```
<i [ngClass]="{'mod3-0': (obsCount | async) %3 == 0, 'mod3-1' : (obsCount | async) %3 == 1, 'mod3-2': (obsCount | async) %3 == 2 }">CSS CLASS CHANGES</i>
```

A simple app.ts would be:

```
import {Component,Pipe,NgZone} from '@angular/core'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [`
    i { width: 50px height: 100px; }
    i.mod3-0 {border: solid 3px yellow; }
    i.mod3-1 {border: solid 3px orange; }
    i.mod3-2 {border: solid 3px red; }
  `],
  template: `
    <i [ngClass]="{'mod3-0': (obsCount | async) %3 == 0, 'mod3-1' : (obsCount | async) %3 == 1, 'mod3-2': (obsCount | async) %3 == 2 }">CSS CLASS CHANGES</i>
    `
  })
export class App {
  constructor(): void { 
    this.obsCount = Observable
      .interval(1000);
  }
}
```